# How to jqGrid dynamic multiselecet?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, checkbox, jqgrid

I hava jqGrid checkbox column,This dynamic build

```
                colNames: ['Id', 'True/False'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', sorttype: "int", hidden: false },
                {
                    name: "Selected", index: 'Selected', width: 70, align: "center",
                    formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false },
                    editable: false, editoptions: { value: "True:False", defaultValue: "No" },
                    stype: "select", searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ["eq", "ne"],
                        value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No"
                    },
                },
```

this code selected columns is checkbox how to this column is multiple selection with its own feature jqGrid

Multiselect: true

And I cant checkbox value (true or false ) How can I do it? ;

If selected column value is true, get multiselect (jqGrid feature) true
If selected column false,get multiselect column false

Thank you in advance for your help. I wish you a good day.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is sensitive on the code:

To enable multiselection use the following code:

```
$("#grid_id").jqGrid({
  ...
  multiselect : true,
  ...
});
```

To get the selected rows when a multiselect is enabled do:

```
var selectedRows =  $("#grid_id").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
```

The selectedRows variable is array which every element is a selected row id. If notihing is selected the array is empty - i.e selectedRows.length = 0;

Comment: Thank you answer; but not find that the column name in checkbox is value == selected rows value        example --
While the grid is loading (I have 5 rows ===3 true select 2 false select )

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the problem. Did you mean that your data contain columns where some are checked and some not? In this case the solution is other.